# Referring to a setting in an sbt root project from a sub project

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I refer to a `baseDirectory` of a root project from within sub-projects in a multi-project sbt build? Like

```
lazy val full: Project = Project(
  id = "full",
  base = file("."),
  ..
)

lazy val sub = Project(
  id = "sub",
  base = file("sub"),
  ..
  settings = Seq(
    javaSource in Compile := full.settings.baseDirectory / "foo" / "src"
  )
)
```

This attempt just gives me:

```
: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method settings in trait Project of type (ss: sbt.Def.Setting[_]*)sbt.Project
and  method settings in trait ProjectDefinition of type => Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]
match expected type ?
    javaSource in Compile := full.settings.baseDirectory / "foo" / "src",
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sbt, projects are just another setting *axis* (along with configurations and tasks). So you can use the `in` operator to access the value of a setting in another project. To get the value of the `baseDirectory` setting key in the project `full`, you would write

```
(baseDirectory in full).value
```

Hence, your complete `javaSource` setting should be:

```
javaSource in Compile := (baseDirectory in full).value / "foo" / "src"
```

See the documentation on [Scopes in sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html) for the whole story.

(Note that accessing the `settings` *method* of a `Project` rarely does what one wants. I believe it is only relevant when write custom *commands*.)

Comment: Any idea how to get a reference to `full` by name, for the case where your subproject has a separate `build.sbt` file and `full` isn't in scope?

Comment: Don't use separate `build.sbt` files for subprojects. It never ends well. Only use `.sbt` files at the top of your project directory tree. That said, you can use `ProjectReference("full")`, IIRC (or something resembling that).